# Relational databases and foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I just have a couple of questions about references, foreign keys and associations in rails. Ive read documentation but still a bit confused.

1. When you type `t.references :tweets` for example in a migration, why does this then turn into `bigint` in the schema?
2. Is `foreign key :true` the part of the code that links the two tables?
3. In addition to question 2, what role does `belongs to` and `has many` have in the models that differs from `foreign key true`, as i thought that the schema would be able to tell which table `has many` and `belongs to` depending on which id is in the other table.

Answer (score 2):

Rails switched over to `BIGINT` by default in version 5.0 because [32-bit unsigned values can overflow and force your database read-only](https://m.signalvnoise.com/update-on-basecamp-3-being-stuck-in-read-only-as-of-nov-8-922am-cst/).

The `foreign_key: true` part has the effect of ensuring data integrity between two tables. You can't insert values that don't exist.

`belongs_to` and `has_many` establish different ends of the same relationship. These cannot necessarily be intuited from the schema itself, and it's often the case that these relationships need to be customized with options.